# Would it be possible to make a container that induces sleep?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, sleep

I had a dream the other night about an alien invasion. In this dream, I was one of the first people to be aware that the aliens had landed, and of course I wanted to warn others. The aliens were locking me into a big box for the night, but secretly I had a mobile phone in my hand; I was planning to alert people by text once the aliens had shut the box and gone away. Unfortunately, as soon as the last latch on the box slipped into place, I fell instantly asleep, and (within the dream) only woke up again when the box was reopened.

**Would this actually be possible, with science as we know it? If so, how would it be done?**

Requirements:

- some kind of sleep-inducing ray
- a container which, when shut, releases said rays (perhaps by closing a circuit)
- instantaneous effect: a person subjected to said rays wouldn't even have time to make a call before falling asleep
- immediate reawakening once the circuit is opened again and the rays stop operating

In other words, a person locked within such a box would be asleep for *exactly* the period the box is closed, no longer and no shorter.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with tagging on this site. Feel free to edit.

Comment: "some kind of sleep-inducing ray" - why would it need to be a ray?

Comment: Just fill the chamber with a gas designed to make you unconscious.

Comment: @Gryphon Would that act quickly enough?

Comment: If your aliens have interstellar travel, I'm sure they could come up with something to put you to sleep in seconds.  Maybe even have nanobots for you to breathe in before the box is closed, and when it is, simply have the nanobots release the knockout stuff into the bloodstream.

Comment: Love the username btw.  Robert Jordan ftw.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP isn't made aware of it.

Comment: This chamber is also known as a "lecture hall".

Comment: After answering, I thought it might be prudent to ask 'how long' you want people to be asleep.  My answer works for a good 8 hours, but not for, say, a year.

Comment: Um, you may need to see a psychiatrist about that dream...

Answer (score 4):

**A regulated dosage of [Chloroform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroform), or trichloromethane.**

Simply produce the amount needed and release it into the little <strike>coffin</strike> black box, but the aliens should strictly regulate the amount - too much could kill someone with breathing problems or even a physically fit person.

This regular anesthetic was used in surgery, and put people to sleep.

In science today, there is no such 'ray' that I know of that wouldn't kill you, but put you to sleep.

Comment: I suppose this doesn't answer the question, because it requests a 'ray,' but such a simpler solution is available.  Occam's Razor again.

Answer (score 2):

**Frequency Specific Pulsed Electromagnetic Field**

Ah this is an interesting question ! For sure the most straight forward way of doing it is a consistent gas mix to induce sleep chemically.  However, there are some studies to suggest that magnetic fields (Pulsed magnetic fields as opposed to constant, which the WHO have found there to be little scientific evidence to support the idea of electromagnetic hypersensitivity) have the ability to affect the brains abilities to sleep.

In therapeutic PEMFs for instance, it has been found that this field and intensity was effective in reducing sleep disturbances in 83% of the exposed group, compared with 57% in the controls, which further suggests that some kind of pulsed EMFs could induce a state of constant sleep.

Studies references : https://www.drpawluk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/PEMFs-and-Sleep-References.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple the aliens pumped your chamber full of sleeping gas that is used widely in medical procedures today puts people to sleep for a predetermined time based on the person's weight.